# Vue js passing data owned by component to methods owned by component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Trying to pass different arrays that are within "data" of a vue component to methods within the same vue component. I am trying to do this to have different variables be affected by the same method without having to have an individual method for each variable.

Tried having the variable be passed as a parameter to the method and it did not respond as expected. It seemed as though the variable being passed was a copy of the data variable rather than the actual value. I want to do this to allow the data to be modified in a method before being displayed on the page

Example data:

```
data () {
   return { 
      a: [],
      b: []
  }
}
```

How I'd like watchers to work:

```
a {
   this.method(this.a)
}

b {
   this.method(this.b)
}
```

Methods:

```
method(value) {
   value.add(1)
}
```

Result currently would be a and b not be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Based on your comments it looks like what you are trying to do is reuse a method in your component to mutate two different arrays in your viewmodel.

You can create a method that gets a collection, the value and an action that you want to run.

**NOTE**: This might end up making your html bindings a bit messy, as you would need to have something like:

```
<button type="button" @click="this.mutate(a, 'a', (c, v) => c.push(v))">Add to a</button>
```

Here's a sample snippet where a shared method is used to mutate and filter the array. I added wrapper methods to keep the html bindings clean (which ends up with the same number of methods but less repetition).

```js
Vue.component('some-component', {
   template: `
   <div>
     <div>a: {{a}}</div>
     <div>b: {{b}}</div>
     <button type="button" @click="onAdd(a, 'a')">Add to a</button>
     <button type="button" @click="onSplice(a, 1)">Splice a</button>
     <br>
     <button type="button" @click="onAdd(b, 'b')">Add to b</button>
     <button type="button" @click="onSplice(b, 1)">Splice b</button>
   </div>
   `,
   data:() => ({ a: [], b: [] }),
   methods: {
       mutate(collection, value, callback){
          callback(collection, value);
       },
       onAdd(collection, value) {
           this.mutate(collection, value, (c, v) => c.push(v));
       },
       onSplice(collection, value) {
            this.mutate(collection, value, (c, v) => c.splice(0, value));
       }
   }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <some-component></some-component>
</div>
```

Comment: My mistake, I was writing this quickly and forgot to write this before my method calls in my theoretical watchers. I have been calling methods with this in front of it. I believe that the way you have things setup also works for me, but only if I am not trying to mutate the data value. The method you have is just showing the length of the list, but I would like it to be mutated in the method itself by having something pushed to it, or have it be filtered etc.

Comment: The reason for this is that I want to have the new data sent in the watcher have some calculations performed on it before displaying it on the page

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer to cover that scenario.

Comment: actually ran into another issue. Seems like this works fine for the example you provided, but when passing the collection to use (i.e. a or b) to my methods within watchers the data variables are not changed

Comment: Tried to build an example that will show the failure I'm dealing with. Everything is working fine in the examples I build though so I'm not able to replicate the failure. It must be something else that I'm doing in addition that's causing the problem, I'll look into it further and update this if I figure out what's causing it.Your solution does fix the issue as described by me, it looks like something else is amiss though.

Comment: How are you declaring your watchers?

Comment: I ended up getting things to work with computed properties instead of watchers. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Watchers must be functions, you can do:

```
  watch: {
    a: function(aNewValue) {
      this.method(aNewValue)
    }
  }
```

Anyway, if you intend that every time a variable changes, a change in another variable is triggered, you should use a computed property.

Comment: Ended up taking the computed property approach and getting this to work